# Vue - Better to publish .vue file or a compiled component?

Tags: node.js, npm, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend

When writing custom components is it better to publish the `.vue` file directly or to publish a compiled version using webpack/other-bundling-tool ?

Bonus: Is there an official document regarding conventions to follow when publishing custom components?

EDIT: What are the pros and cons of either method?

Comment: I expect this is largely opinion based, but why not both? Offer a dist folder with compiled version in addition to the .vue file elsewhere. There is no official document that I am aware of.

Comment: What are the pros and cons of either approach?

Answer (score 4):

I've published a few open source projects and from experience I can say that it's better to publish your code - or rather, set the main entry point - as a compiled distributable for a few reasons:

Firstly, by outputting a UMD module you are creating a distributable that works across all environments (webpack, browserify, CDN, AMD) and it's as simple as adding the following to your webpack config:

```
output: {
    ...
    library: 'MyPackageName',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    umdNamedDefine: true
},
```

Secondly, most developers using webpack will exclude `babel-loader` from compiling scripts in their `node_modules` folder by doing something like:

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  exclude: /node_modules/
```

}

So, if developers need to compile your code themselves and you have anything in your project that is not a `.vue` file that uses `ES2015` (e.g. a mixin) then you would need to tell developers to apply `babel-loader` to your project folder in their `webpack` config.

As for `browserify`developers having to compile your project, you would need to add `vueify` and `babelify` as transforms to `package.json` (they actually can't set this up themselves) and tell those developers that those are dependencies and get them to set up an appropriate `.babelrc` file.

All that setup can be a nightmare for `devs`, many will have little knowledge about their build process, so won't know about excludes, they won't know about transforms, they will just get a bunch of errors and either remove your package or create issues on your repo.

And that's just for the two most common build processes, you will still probably want a `CDN` and you will still want to allow those using `AMD` modules to use your package, so a UMD module is the way to go.

That said, you should still distribute the `.vue` files themselves, which will also allow devs to compile your project if they have advanced configuration requirements.